# Why this answer was downvoted?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

Hello everyone I want to know that the answer (link given below) was almost complete and correct I think that the answer didn't require any update but why it was downvoted?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/474362/

Comment: It's one downvote. That's really not worth a meta post.

Comment: Well it doesn't look like it really answers the question to me; OP is concerned about "equal & Olopposite" forces while you talk about coefficient of restitution without much about how that matters.

Comment: Regarding the comments on you answer, please be careful not to violate [the Code of Conduct](https://physics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Your comments can be seen as unfriendly or even rude and might get flagged.

Answer (score 3):

It was downvoted by me.

Originally you answered as if all dissipating forces could be ignored, without stating that in your answer.  I tried to point you to the issue, and you chose to make the edit, but also accused me of not thinking.  You can see in the comments that I pointed out that I thought it was rude, along with your further comments, so I left the downvote.

Comment: Hi friend,I was in great trouble at that time due to some reasons and was passing time on this website so I automatically wrote anything.I am just a 12 year old kid so please don't take it personally.

Comment: The expectations for behavior on this site are the same for members of all ages.

Comment: Downvotes are for quality if posts not person. If you find it rude flag it.

Comment: @user541396 I downvoted it because it was originally low quality, and didn't retract my downvote because the user was incredibly disrespectful about making the improvements.  I'm pretty sure I did flag the rude comment, but I wasn't going to also retract my downvote after that, and since votes can be chosen by individual members, and I wasn't targeting that user with successive downvotes, it was within my rights.